# Toggle between 3 functions on mouse click

Tags: javascript, click, addeventlistener

I am adding an `addEventListener` to a picture on my website.

The goal is that every time the user clicks this picture (`album-cover-art`) a function will be called (`function (event)`), **which will toggle between 3 functions**

```
document.getElementsByClassName("album-cover-art")[0].addEventListener("click", function (event){

});
```

these are the 3 functions i want to toggle between:

```
setCurrentAlbum(albumPicasso);
setCurrentAlbum(albumMarconi);
setCurrentAlbum(albumGreenDay);
```

how can include these 3 function calls in the eventListener that when the picture is clicked it will toggle between them??

```
document.getElementsByClassName("album-cover-art")[0].addEventListener("click", function (event){
//toggle between the 3 functions below:
setCurrentAlbum(albumPicasso);
setCurrentAlbum(albumMarconi);
setCurrentAlbum(albumGreenDay);
});
```

**NOTE:**

- This is a challenge where can i only use JavaScript **NOT** JQuery

  - It must toggle between them forever, not a loop which will have an end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create an array containg all choise then , using an index , select choise and increment this last every click , if index equals to the arrays length then return to the first index (0) ,

```
var index= 1;
var albums = [albumPicasso,albumMarconi,albumGreenDay];
document.getElementsByClassName("album-cover-art")[0].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  if(index == albums.length) index = 0;
  setCurrentAlbum(albums[index]);
  index++;
});
```

See beelow snippet as an explaining sample :

```js
var albumPicasso = "https://dummyimage.com/300x300/500/f0f",
albumMarconi = "https://dummyimage.com/300x300/550/ff0",
albumGreenDay = "https://dummyimage.com/300x300/555/0ff";

var index= 0;
var albums = [albumPicasso,albumMarconi,albumGreenDay];
document.getElementsByClassName("album-cover-art")[0].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  if(index == albums.length) index = 0;
  setCurrentAlbum(albums[index]);
  index++;
});

function setCurrentAlbum(album){
  document.getElementsByClassName("album-cover-art")[0].style.backgroundImage = "url('"+album+"')";
}
```

```css
.album-cover-art {
  background-image : url('https://dummyimage.com/300x300/500/0ff');
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="album-cover-art">
  
</div>
```

Comment: @for those whose downvoting , why don't add a comment to explain your 
unpleasantness ............. !!!!

Comment: Thank you,
This works and seems to be the most simple and clear for my understanding, even though i'm sure the others worked as well

Comment: @samibirnbaum I'm glad :)

Answer (score 0):

*For all downvoters: just because you don't like the pattern it doesn't mean the solution is wrong. Type your own, better answer and let the asker pick the one he prefer. Also, if you're downvoting supply the reason (as a comment) for learning purposes, for me and the asker. thanks.*

**Here is the snippet you may find usefull:**

```js
albumClickCounter = 0;

document.getElementsByClassName("album-cover-art")[0].addEventListener("click", function (event){
  if(window.albumClickCounter % 3 === 0) setCurrentAlbum(albumPicasso);
  if(window.albumClickCounter % 3 === 1) setCurrentAlbum(albumMarconi);
  if(window.albumClickCounter % 3 === 2) setCurrentAlbum(albumGreenDay);
  
  window.albumClickCounter++;
});

var setCurrentAlbum = function(album) { alert(album); }
var albumPicasso = 1;
var albumMarconi = 2;
var albumGreenDay = 3;
```

```css
.album-cover-art {
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="album-cover-art"></div>
```

For demonstration purposes albums are numbers, but the logic can be whatever you like. Adjust to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

use as below

```
var previouParam="";
 document.getElementsByClassName("album-cover-art")
 [0].addEventListener("click", function (event){
    if(previouParam==""){
       setCurrentAlbum("albumPicasso");
     }else if(previouParam=="albumPicasso"){
       setCurrentAlbum("albumMarconi");
      }else{
        previouParam="";
        setCurrentAlbum("albumGreenDay");
     }

 });
```